# Odoo 10: Field 'carrier_tracking_ref' does not exist

Tags: xml, inheritance, odoo-10

Ok, so here's my issue.  I'm attempting to add information to delivery.view_picking_withcarrier_out_form.  and here is my xml.

```
<record id="stock_carrier_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">stock.carrier.form.view</field>
  <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="delivery.view_picking_withcarrier_out_form" />
  <field name="priority" eval="99"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//div[@name='tracking']" position="after">
      <field name="incoming_carrier_id"/>
    </xpath>
  </field>
</record>
```

Here is the python:

```
class StockPicking(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.picking'

    #add incoming carrier information
    incoming_carrier_id = fields.Many2one('delivery.carrier', string='Carrier')
```

with this  xml code i'm getting the error "Field `carrier_tracking_ref` does not exist" where carrier_tracking_ref is defined in delivery/modules/stock_picking.py and is already defined in delivery.view_picking_withcarrier_out_form.   I am able to use this field in the method of a calculated field which is added to stock.vpicktree however without issue.
Python:

```
#assign the carrier id for the treeview
@api.model
def _compute_carrier_tree(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.carrier_id:
            rec.carrier_id_tree_view = rec.carrier_id
        elif rec.incoming_carrier_id:
            rec.carrier_id_tree_view = rec.incoming_carrier_id

carrier_id_tree_view = fields.Many2one('delivery.carrier', string='Carrier', compute='_compute_carrier_tree')
```

xml:

```
<record id="stock_carrier_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">stock.carrier.tree.view</field>
  <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.vpicktree" />
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_id']" position="after">
      <field name="carrier_id_tree_view"/>
    </xpath>
  </field>
</record>
```

Why would adding a field to a view keep the program from recognizing a pre-existing field from a different module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I feel kinda stupid on this one.  I forgot to check my dependancies.